# In Python, can I make another module's functions available to users importing my module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use `functools` and `itertools` in pretty much every module. I find them so essential that I'm annoyed that I have to import their functions in every module I write. I'd like to create a module, let's call it `mytools` that imports all of the functions from `functools` and `itertools` and makes their functions directly available to any module that imports `mytools`.

I'm specifically interested in manipulating the import system in this way, so please avoid sidestepping this approach in solutions just for the sake of making functools and itertools easily available.

Comment: You should just automate your python file headers using a template in your IDE.

Comment: ... have you tried creating a module `mytools` that itself imports what you want? What exactly is your question here, what difficulty are you encountering?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why do you start your comment with a "..."? The only interpretation I can guess is that you want to express that the question is stupid or misguided. Is that what you wanted to express? What exactly is the point of your comment? I think I made my question perfectly clear. If you think that it doesn't warrant submission on this site, save your unnecessary comments and vote to close.

Comment: Because your question seems to answer itself, and I don't understand what difficulty you are encountering. I am asking for you to elaborate. The '...' expresses my lack of understanding you.

Comment: It's because the question is too broad. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Create a directory `mytools` and add it's parent directory to your python path.  Inside that directory create a file `__init__.py` with

```
from functools import *
from itertools import *
```

Then from other files you can do

```
import mytools
print(mytools.partial)
# <class 'functools.partial'>
```

Comment: There seems to be no reason to use a package here. Also, adding the `mytools` directory itself to the path won't make `mytools` importable, and manually messing with the path is usually a bad way to go in general.

Comment: What if both modules have a function/object using the same name but with different signatures? That is why `from module import *` is frowned upon.

Comment: @user2357112 Then where would you place it to make it discoverable?

Comment: @PauloScardine itertools and functools don't share any (meaningful) attributes. If they did, you could manually get around that by renaming them in the above.  `import name from itertools; import name from functools as other_name`

Comment: You could also do `from mytools import *`. Then, you just populate the `mytools` namespace (by doing imports etc) how you want, and your new module starts with the same namespce.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: In the same directory as the other modules, or make a `setup.py` and `pip install` the module (probably in a virtualenv), or maybe there's some sort of IDE-specific thing to do if you use an IDE (I don't).

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own class that imports and defines them as being self names:

```
import itertools
import functools


class MyTools(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.itertools = itertools
        self.functools = functools
```

You would then just have to import the file containing this class:

```
from mytools.py import MyTools
mytools = MyTools()

print(mytools.functools.partial)
```